# Can the output of a probit regression with a Z-score predictor be interpreted as a standardised effect size?

Tags: regression, binary-data, standardization, probit, z-score

I want to obtain a standardised effect size for a regression with a binary outcome. If I standardise the (continuous) predictor and run a probit regression, the resulting coefficient can be interpreted as in the difference in Z-score outcome per one unit increase in the change in the Z-score predictor. Therefore, is this the same as a standardised regression coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can interpret the coefficient of a probit model like that. For instance,  I think that your independent variable going from 1 to 2 is different than going from 2 to 3. You may want to read up on interpreting probit parameters. There's a good explanation here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/output/probit-regression/